# simple inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality

I want to show that this inequality holds for $0<p,q<1$.

> $ q^{-p}(1-q)^{p-1} \geq (1-p)^{p-1}p^{-p} $

I have tried to divide it into 3 cases:

1. $0<p<q<1$
2. $0<q<p$
3. $p=q$ (obvious)

But it doesn't seem to work!

Comment: Is it right:$q^{-p}$ and $p^{-p}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$$
f(x)=-p\log(x)+(p-1)\log(1-x)\tag{1}
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=-\frac{p}{x}-\frac{p-1}{1-x}\\
f''(x)&=\frac{p}{x^2}+\frac{1-p}{(1-x)^2}
\end{align}\tag{2}
$$
$f'(x)=0$ when
$$
\frac{p}{x}=\frac{1-p}{1-x}\tag{3}
$$
One solution to $(3)$ is when $x=p$, and since $f''(x)\gt0$ for all $x$, this is a unique minimum.

Therefore, for any $q$, we must have
$$
f(q)\ge f(p)\tag{4}
$$
which implies
$$
q^{-p}(1-q)^{p-1}\ge p^{-p}(1-p)^{p-1}\tag{5}
$$